# MySQL Query for one-to-many relation and only-one-row return

Tags: mysql, sql

**The situation**
I have a tabe `userproducts` which stores the products and I have a table `offers` which stores all competitors for a product. Also I have another table called `sellers` which stores informations about the sellers/competitors.

**What I want**
I want now, that I can search trough my products and also get the information which is the `lowest_price` and what is the `name of this competitor`.

**What I have**
I made it so far, that I can say it shall give me the lowest_price and the name for one asin (=product). Here it is.

```
SELECT (o.price+o.shipping) AS lowest_price,
       s.seller_name AS seller_name
  FROM offers AS o
       LEFT JOIN sellers AS s
            ON (o.userinfos_id = s.userinfos_id 
                AND o.marketplace_id = s.marketplace_id 
                AND o.merchant_id = s.seller_id)
 WHERE o.userinfos_id = ? 
       AND o.marketplace_id = ? 
       AND o.asin = ? 
       AND o.merchant_id != ?
 ORDER BY 
       (o.price+o.shipping) ASC
 LIMIT 1)
```

*If you see any performance leak in here, please feel free to report*

**What is missing**
But what is missing though, is how I can get this information for all of my asins. Not just for one. I can not see the missing link. I tried a solution where I made this to a subquery and put it in the `SELECT`  like this:

```
SELECT userproducts.*, 
       ( "HERE the query from the top ) 
  FROM userproducts 
 WHERE ...
```

But instead with a result, MySQL responded to me with this error message

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

I just want to search through my products, and mysql should give me back also the information about the `lowest_price`. Can you help me make my query work?

Comment: Your question is not clear but what is understand you want the min price for all not for one so you can use `SELECT MIN(o.price+o.shipping)) AS lowest_price` ..... GROUP BY o.asin` remove `LIMIT 1 , AND o.asin = ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT userproducts.*, 
       topQuery.*
  FROM userproducts, 
       ( "HERE the query from the top ) topQuery
 WHERE ..
```

Comment: Well i guess, i celebrated a bit to early. At the moment he gives back the correct product and also `lowest_price`, but not for that particular product, instead always for the same product. What do i have to change on my `topQuery`

Comment: Then you don't need limit 1 but instead you should calculate the seller_name and lowest_price for each product_id. Guess you should add GROUP BY product_id in the top query

Comment: After that you can JOIN userproducts and topQuery ON product_id

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your tables structure and join conditions, but maybe this example would be useful:

```
SELECT u.field1, u.field2, 
   min(o.price+o.shipping) AS lowest_price,
   s.seller_name AS seller_name
FROM userproducts u
   LEFT JOIN offers AS o
        ON o.userinfos_id = u.userinfos_id
        AND o.marketplace_id = u.marketplace_id
        AND o.asin = u.asin 
        AND o.merchant_id = u.merchant_id
   LEFT JOIN sellers AS s
        ON (o.userinfos_id = s.userinfos_id 
            AND o.marketplace_id = s.marketplace_id 
            AND o.merchant_id = s.seller_id)
 GROUP BY u.field1, u.field2, s.seller_name
```